# Java EntityManager nullpointer

Tags: java, eclipselink

I'm trying to retrieve a simple JSON list, convert this JSON array to Eclipselink objects and put them in postgres. Although i keep getting nullpointers from the EntityManager and i've lost track.

Im calling my controller from a test webservice:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Test", urlPatterns = {"/Test"})
public class Test extends HttpServlet {


    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            // HERE I CALL CUSTOM METHODS
            AppController appConn = new AppController();
            appConn.updateAppList();
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

In the controller im trying to persist these converted objects:

```
public class AppController {
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="UserPU")
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


    public AppController() {

    }

    public void updateAppList() {
        try {
            URLController urlConn = new URLController(Config.allAppsURL);
            JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(urlConn.toString());
            JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
            jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("applist");
            JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("apps");

            ArrayList<SteamApp> apps = new ArrayList<App>(){};
            for(int i = 0; i < jarray.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject jsteamObject = jarray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                App app = new SteamApp(jsteamObject.get("appid").getAsLong(), jsteamObject.get("name").toString());
                apps.add(app);
                //System.out.println("App[" + app.getAppid() + ", " + app.getName() + "] \n\r");
            }

            em.persist(apps);
            em.flush();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AppController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Im calling this method from a webservice, only to test it out. Im planning to use seperate threads for pulling it in, in the background.

But what am i doing wrong? This persistance setup is very confusing?!?

Comment: What container are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that the `AppController` is not a managed object and so no dependency injection will be performed in it. You either need to inject the `AppController` into the servlet as a managed bean or manually initialise the `EntityManagerFactory` using the `javax.persistence.Persistence` utility class. If the `AppController` is fully stateless you could inject it as a CDI managed bean using the `@Inject` annotation.

Another problem if you do inject the AppController is that the `EntityManagerFactory` is only injected after the `AppController` object has been constructed, but fields are initialised during object construction. When a new AppController object is created, the `emf` field is initialised to null and so the attempt to initialise the `em` field will lead to a null pointer exception.

EntityManagers are also not thread-safe, so if you do go the route of injecting it through CDI, you will need to create the `EntityManager` from the factory in the `updateAppList()` method. This has the drawback that transaction management and closing the entity manager will be your own responsibility.

An alternative is to convert the `AppController` to an EJB stateless session bean and then injecting this in the servlet. In this case you don't need to inject the EntityManagerFactory, but can directly inject the `EntityManager` using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation.